# Javascript/Lodash - Removing an item from an array (has the same id)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to remove an item from an array that has several objects, where in some cases it may has the same id. Here is the array :

```
var array = [{
"outletId": "OjHJ104",
"items": [{
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    }
  ]
 }];
```

Let's say I want to remove the item with the objectId : **lQnt4dmiPs**

Using the below :

```
_.remove(array, { objectId: 'lQnt4dmiPs' });
```

It's true that it removes the item; however it removes all the objects that has the objectId : **lQnt4dmiPs** which is not the wanted behavior. I want to remove it only once (as the remove function triggers onclick..).

I believe that I am missing something here or rather I should use another lodash function.

Comment: It returns an array of the removed elements.  So, from that returned array, just remove the first one, and add them back to the original object.

Comment: @Amy can you please extend more ? A example will be appreciated.

Comment: First, can you elaborate on what you mean by " the remove function triggers onclick"?

Comment: @Amy I have a button with a `-` and `+` (an add to cart button) when the user clicks on `-` it should reduce the quantity of that item from the cart meaning that it should remove only one item from the the cart that has the same `id` to reduce its quantity.

Comment: Okay, so its phrased backwards?  Onclick triggers the remove?

Comment: As I said before when the user clicks, the `remove` function fire up to find the element that has the same id and remove it.

Comment: I'm confused. The question says "the remove function triggers onclick".  How does remove trigger the click?

Comment: If you only want to remove one, you could use `_.findIndex` to get the index of the first item with matching id, then use `Array.splice` method to remove only that first item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lodash doesn't have a function to do that directly ([lodash#1114](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1114) closed as wontfix), but you can use `_.findIndex` and `Array#splice`:

```
var index = _.findIndex(array, { objectId: 'lQnt4dmiPs' })
// The second argument is the number of items to remove.
var removedItem = array.splice(index, 1)
```

Comment: Good catch mate, simple and beautiful ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can always just quickly roll your own solution, it is quite trivial.

```js
var array = [{
"outletId": "OjHJ104",
"items": [{
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    }
  ]
 }];
  const remove = (arr, id) => {
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
         if(arr[i].objectId === id) {
            arr.splice(i,1);
            return;
         }
      }
  }
  remove(array[0].items,'lQnt4dmiPs');
  console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findIndex`, which only finds the first instance. Then `filter` the array to remove that index number's element.

```js
var array = [{
"outletId": "OjHJ104",
"items": [{
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lQnt4dmiPs",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": false,
    },
    {
        "objectId": "lC6C96Ekua",
        "inCart": true,
    }
  ]
 }];
 
 const remove = (arr, str) => {
   const elIdx = arr.findIndex(({objectId}) => objectId === str)
   return arr.filter((_, idx) => idx !== elIdx)
 }
 
 console.log(remove(array[0].items, "lQnt4dmiPs"))
```